# Why would the gods be labelled?

Tags: culture, fantasy-races

The gods in this setting are extremely powerful but limited beings, who are similar to humans in their mind and decisions. The gods are the highest powers in the world but originate from reproduction in the same way as other organisms.

The main feature separating the gods from other creatures is that many gods have labels written on their body in various places, that show names, titles, or qualities of the labelled god. The gods have various levels of labelling, and some gods are not labelled at all. Every faction of gods has both labelled and unlabelled members, and some of the most powerful and lawless gods are also labelled. Several gods have inaccurate labels.

What reason could there be for the gods to be labelled?

Comment: Please clarify: is this a tattoo the gods choose to obtain, or is it a naturally-occurring birthmark? What are examples of "names, titles, or qualities of the labelled god?"

Comment: Exactly and - so far - only the same reason that led you to come up with that idea… unless "to distinguish them from ordinary beings" works for you.

When the main feature separating your gods from other creatures is that "many" gods have labels, what about the others? As Posted, you seem to be saying that labels neither confer nor signify Godhood… so what role do they really play?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### You Label Me, I Label you...

So we're talking fantasy and magic, so rules are a bit loose. Your universe is a magical one, and magic is often intrinsically linked to the power of words. The words wizards say invoke powerful forces of the universe. But while humans and their words invoke these power of these words to manipulate the magic, your gods are a step closer. Your gods interact with the power of language directly, touching the mystic words themselves, and can thus directly manipulate reality.

You specified that the labels are not always accurate. So they don't correlate with the meaning of the words, or the judgement of some even higher power. That gives us a few options.

- **Contamination**: The essences of these words is clinging to your gods like magical stains. A wizard is at "arms length" when contacting magic, but the gods touch it directly. Interacting with a word frequently leaves an impression that has a physical manifestation. Conversely, touching magic radically different than what one deals with regularly might also leave it's mark as inexperienced hands mishandle the power. While the gods are powerful, this is the essence of their power. They don't know how to remove these stains. They may be useful, connecting the gods to underlying mystic power, so then they wouldn't WANT to remove them even if they could. If they are accidents, then younger gods who have been shown the proper way to use magic won't get them because they know how not to.
- **Artifacts**: These labels were once attached to different beings. World mythologies inevitably refer to ancient, pre-existing pantheons of gods who are overthrown by the current gods. These labels represent things that once made sense in another frame of reference. So if god X ('the Sea Lord) killed or overthrew god Y ('the whale of the universe') a thousand years ago, X may now find himself marked with "whale." These artifacts may or may not contain intrinsic power, so when Apollo kills Python the oracle of Delphi, he may take on the power of the oracle. Or they can be things made by previous god just for vanity - divine swag that now sticks to their descendants like a bad tattoo.
- **Divine bad judgement**: Like tattoos, labels are forever. Your gods are no wiser than humans, and humans aren't all that wise. If your gods are long-lived, they may have used permanent magical means to title themselves or others. But the role of gods, and the motives they feel about things, are changeable. The god of fire this year may be a god of fiery war next year OR a god of fiery sun and agriculture. And things may have very different meanings in different contexts. MLK are the initials of Martin Luther King, but once long ago the three letters stood for Moloch, fiery god of human child sacrifice.

In all of these cases, the labels are most likely attached to gods who are old, and thus have experienced many things for the first time, or the bold, who are exploring outside their comfort zone in unfamiliar places magically and engaging in risky divine combat and reckless behaviors. Even if there's no intrinsic power associated with the labels, having a label is a mark that you are someone to be watched and reckoned with.

Answer (score 15):

**In the Beginning there was the Words.**

The primordial universe contained only the Words. The material universe was formed as the Words Spoke themselves into physical form.

Most of the Words are now gone. The few that remain carry great power. Being some of the earliest living creatures, the Gods discovered how to prevent a Word from Speaking itself -- namely attach the Word to a living creature. This keeps the Word from Speaking itself until the creature dies.

Thus all known Words are attached to a God in case it is needed later.
Typically they prefer to carry words relevant to their nature, as this makes the power easier to use. These Words are accurate labels. But you might also have several redundant Words in case your nature changes; get a Word as an honorific, or simply be carrying it for someone else. These are inaccurate labels.

Answer (score 7):

**It is the work of the god of labels**

Of all the gods powers, one of the first gods got the power of labeling. His power was to materialize labels everywhere.
Power crazed and driven by the enthusiasm of the youth, this god started to label everything: animals, trees, other gods, mortals, stones... Some were correct, other were mockeries (that god was a bit of a prankster).

But eons have passed, and now this god has become wiser and has decided to use his powers only in moderation. Of all the things that he labeled centuries before, mortals died, while the labels on the landscape were canceled by erosion.
Only the labels on the gods, since they are immortal and their bodies can't change, were left intact.

Answer (score 5):

**The world is an art project.**

Labelled gods are some of the original pieces of the project.  They were labelled by their creator or creators.  There are other things in this world that are not gods but are also labelled - artifacts of the original project setup.

Unlabelled gods and other things are not original to the project but evolved within it, are secondary creations, or are later additions from other projects.  They might carry labels from those other projects that are not relevant or make no sense in their current enivrons.

Answer (score 4):

**Achievement gained: Kill 100 humans with a fork**

Your gods are just as vain as humans, so they tattoo on themselves when they do something of note. Killed another god, destroyed a village, started/ended a human war etc. They can also use them to keep a tally of of things like the number of humans they killed or helped.

Comment: Like Maui in Disney's Moana, lol.

Answer (score 3):

Like in an army some members exhibit their grades while others keep them hidden, the same happens for your gods.

Reason for showing off one's grade are exhibit of authority and status, for example, while reason for hiding one's grade could be the need to act in covert: who wants to be the primary target of a sniper just because is showing off their rank on the shirt.

Answer (score 3):

The name is the thing, and the true name is the true thing.

By labeling themselves, the gods are invoking great power.

The variation is caused by variation in motives:

- Some powers are just harder to control than others, and so a god needs a label to get good at them.
- Some powers come more naturally to some gods than to others.  If you want to be as good as another god, you may need the label.
- Some gods desire power more than others and use the labels.
- Some gods are lazy and use the labels to replace hard work.

Answer (score 2):

It is a personal ID. The God civilization used IDs, but either they are not compulsory, just convenient to have them (the Denmark or UK model), or maybe they are compulsory from certain age up (much of the rest of the world, minus USA), we mortals just do not know the exact reason (gods can change their appearance for us mortals, so we cannot distinguish the young ones).

Since they found it extremely easy to apply the labels, the need for wearable pieces of paper or plastic never arose.

Answer (score 2):

**Gods are invisible**  Some of them like to be seen so they wear labels with their names on. Tricksome gods can forge the label of another god so as to pretend to be them. Some gods are shy or just like to do godly things in secret. They don't wear labels.

Answer (score 1):

Gods may come into being by sex like other organisms, but that is just part of the truth. They actually emanate from myths - when the myths say they reproduce, they reproduce. It is actually the people's belief in those gods that shape the deities and their stories.

It just so happens that one of the seminal prophets and/or storytellers of this world was also an organization maniac. You know, stereotypical virgo, with a nearly sexual compulsion to have things neatly arranged. The kind of people that buys and uses post-it's, makes schedules for their coworkers, creates processes and comes up with ever new forms and subcomitees.

That [redacted] zealot probably had the designs for the original pantheon in a binder, with color-coded spheres of influence. Gods with wrong or missing labels were later added to the mythos by reformists, heretics, apostathes and messiahs who weren't so crazy about organizing.

This tangentially rhymes with the work of [Nuggan, the Borogravian God of paperclips, correct things in the right place in small desk stationery sets, and unnecessary paperwork](https://wiki.lspace.org/mediawiki/Nuggan).

Answer (score 0):

**The rich gods can afford labels**

Some gods are fashion conscious.  They of course like to wear designer labels as much as possible.